Why I get a non-std C++ exception, RCTFatal, RCTConvertArrayValue error trying to initialize my database?
I am trying to use expo-sqlite to create and initialize a database within my React Native app, using Expo as the handler to test the app with Expo Go on a native iOS device for reference.
openDatabase() was sunset in favor of openDatabaseAsync(). I am unable to initialize a database. I get a non-std C++ exception, RCTFatal, RCTConvertArrayValue error. Sometimes I can get it to work but the database fails to initialize.
// Nutrition Database stored here.
// Done with documentation from sq-lite as certain functions have been sunset.
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';

const nutriDB = await SQLite.openDatabaseAsync('nutritionDB.db');

// Set up the table, only will create if it doesn't exist.
const initializeDatabase = async () => {

  try {

    await nutriDB.execAsync(`PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NutritionInput (
        NutritionInputID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        Date TEXT,
        FoodEntries TEXT,
        MealType TEXT CHECK (MealType IN ('Breakfast', 'Lunch', 'Dinner', 'Snack')),
        TransFat REAL CHECK(TransFat >=0),
        SatFat REAL CHECK (SatFat >= 0),
        TotalCalories REAL CHECK (TotalCalories >=0)
      );
    `);

    console.log('Nutrition table initialized successfully!');

  }

    catch (error) {

      console.error('Error creating the table: ', error);
    }
}

export default { nutriDB, initializeDatabase }

Solutions like WatermelonDB require to forgo the Expo build. I want a solution that works with Expo and the Expo Go app.

I just had this issue. First I checked if SQLite.openDatabaseSync worked, which it did, which meant it was an async issue.
I then put all my async code into a function including connecting to the database (SQLite.openDatabaseAsync) and then called them from a useEffect so they were not called too early.
In your case, something like the following works for me:
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';

const initializeDatabase = async () => {

  try {
    const nutriDB = await SQLite.openDatabaseAsync('nutritionDB.db');
    await nutriDB.execAsync(`PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NutritionInput (
        NutritionInputID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        Date TEXT,
        FoodEntries TEXT,
        MealType TEXT CHECK (MealType IN ('Breakfast', 'Lunch', 'Dinner', 'Snack')),
        TransFat REAL CHECK(TransFat >=0),
        SatFat REAL CHECK (SatFat >= 0),
        TotalCalories REAL CHECK (TotalCalories >=0)
      );
    `);

    console.log('Nutrition table initialized successfully!');

  }

    catch (error) {

      console.error('Error creating the table: ', error);
    }
}


export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Call the async function inside useEffect
    initializeDatabase();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Check the console for database output.</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

